# Create a rights/responsibilities Matrix in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a nice overview of responsibilities in a system, and I have received an output of responsibilities entries in the system in the format of rows of username, responsibility description and responsibility ID.

[image]

I want to transform this list into a matrix such as the following:

I am at a loss as to how to create such a matrix with common Excel functions, however, I am guessing that it has to be simple in some way.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select columns A:C

Under the insert tab select pivot table,

Drag the field UserName to the rows section

Drag Responsibility field to the columns section

Drag Responsibility_ID to the values section, and choose the value count.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you are a beautiful human being. This worked perfectly in the first attempt.